# What format is this kernel image? Can not extract kernel code from it?

Tags: linux-kernel, android, images

I got an android image which contains:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  69206016 Dec 16 17:01 cache.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   6024864 Mar 23  2016 Image
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1108329 Mar  7  2016 ramdisk.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 943718400 Mar  7  2016 system.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 576716800 Dec 16 17:02 userdata.img
```

And it can be booted by android emulator with:

```
./emulator64-ranchu-arm64 -system ./system.img -data ./userdata.img -ramdisk ./ramdisk.img -kernel ./Image -cache ./cache.img     -sysdir ./ -no-window  -verbose -show-kernel
```

Or directly use qemu:

```
./qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64 -cpu cortex-a57 -machine type=ranchu -m 512 -append 'console=ttyAMA0,38400 keep_bootcon earlyprintk=ttyAMA0' -serial mon:stdio -kernel .//Image -initrd .//ramdisk.img -drive index=0,id=sdcard,file=.//system.img -device virtio-blk-device,drive=sdcard -drive index=1,id=userdata,file=.//.//userdata.img -device virtio-blk-device,drive=userdata -drive index=2,id=cache,file=.//cache.img -device virtio-blk-device,drive=cache -drive index=3,id=system,file=.//system.img -device virtio-blk-device,drive=system -netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-device,netdev=mynet -show-cursor -nographic -L lib/pc-bios
```

Now I want to extract kernel code but this image seems different. The usual steps: find the offset of gzip data, split it using `dd`, use gzip to get the vmlinux, does not works on it. Here is the information got from this image:

```
root@Debian:~$ file Image
Image: data

root@Debian:~$ binwalk Image

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4395136       0x431080        Linux kernel version "3.10.0+ (root@jiayy) (gcc version 4.9.x-google 20140827 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #63 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 23 11:27:47 CST 2016"
4407688       0x434188        gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, NULL date (1970-01-01 00:00:00)
5270000       0x5069F0        Unix path: /data2/kernel/goldfish/arch/arm64/include/asm/pgalloc.h
5347656       0x519948        Ubiquiti partition header, header size: 56 bytes, name: "PARTNAME=%s", base address: 0x63697479, data size: 0 bytes
5367856       0x51E830        Unix path: /lib/firmware/updates/3.10.0+
5382775       0x522277        Unix path: /net/ethernet/smsc/smc91x.c
5410863       0x52902F        Unix path: /staging/android/ion/ion.c
5412463       0x52966F        Unix path: /staging/android/ion/ion_heap.c
5412663       0x529737        Unix path: /staging/android/ion/ion_page_pool.c
5412823       0x5297D7        Unix path: /staging/android/ion/ion_system_heap.c
5443853       0x53110D        Copyright string: "Copyright (c) 2006-2007 BalaBit IT Ltd."
5483104       0x53AA60        Neighborly text, "NeighborSolicits"
5483128       0x53AA78        Neighborly text, "NeighborAdvertisementsErrors"
5488754       0x53C072        Neighborly text, "neighbor %.2x%.2x.%pM lost rename link %s to %s"
5710184       0x572168        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "dev", file name length: "0x00000004", file size: "0x00000000"
5710300       0x5721DC        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "dev/console", file name length: "0x0000000C", file size: "0x00000000"
5710424       0x572258        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "root", file name length: "0x00000005", file size: "0x00000000"
5710540       0x5722CC        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
5754880       0x57D000        ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, version 1 (SYSV)
5760064       0x57E440        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian


root@Debian:~$ xxd -g 1 Image|head
0000000: 10 00 00 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0000010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0000020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0000030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 41 52 4d 64 00 00 00 00  ........ARMd....
0000040: f5 03 00 aa 72 00 00 94 0e 00 00 94 16 00 38 d5  ....r.........8.
0000050: e0 03 16 aa fb 00 00 94 f7 03 00 aa 97 1e 00 b4  ................
0000060: 0a 01 00 94 73 00 00 94 9b 1a 00 58 3e 0b 00 10  ....s......X>...
0000070: ec 0a 40 f9 8c 01 1c 8b 80 01 1f d6 1f 20 03 d5  ..@.......... ..
0000080: 40 42 38 d5 1f 20 00 f1 04 18 49 fa 20 17 00 58  @B8.. ....I. ..X
0000090: 00 00 1c 8b 60 00 00 54 1f 00 00 b9 c0 03 5f d6  ....`..T......_.
```

The kernel configuration file can be extracted from offset 0x434188(corresponds to the second segment in the output of binwalk).  I also tried to use extract-vmlinux.sh from google git(https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish/+/android-goldfish-3.10-m-dev/scripts/extract-vmlinux) but it did not work too.

So what format is this kernel image and how can I extract kernel code from it?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a bit late to the party here, but I was just dealing with a vmlinux image very similar to the asker's. Disassembling a raw kernel image like this and analyzing the code is a monstrous task when all you have is the output from `aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -b binary -maarch64 -EL -D vmlinux`.

Fortunately, some beautiful soul out there wrote a tool to convert raw vmlinux images into ELF binary format. This image isn't executable, but it will be understood by a debugger/disassembler such as gdb or [Cutter](https://cutter.re/). It also will attempt to find the embedded symbols and resolve them in the output ELF file. The tool, called vmlinux-to-elf, can be found [here](https://github.com/marin-m/vmlinux-to-elf)

Links:

[Download Cutter](https://cutter.re/)

[Download vmlinux-to-elf](https://github.com/marin-m/vmlinux-to-elf)

Answer (score 1):

This kernel image is the bootable raw binary part of vmlinux, which means it isn't a complete ELF file. Just disassemble it from the beginning to get the kernel code.